# Strange behavior of MySQL command SELECT

Tags: mysql

I don't know why this query ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*),* FROM table1 WHERE .. GROUP BY column1
```

return a syntax error, but ...

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE .. GROUP BY column1
```

... returns normal data.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) for `SELECT` says:

> Use of an unqualified * with other items in the select list may
>   produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified
>   tbl_name.* reference
>   SELECT AVG(score), t1.* FROM t1 ...

So, in your case use this syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), table1.* FROM table1 WHERE .. GROUP BY column1
```